# An application of Lebesgue's Dominated Convergence Theorem. Is that correct?

Tags: limits, probability-theory, measure-theory, expected-value, probability-limit-theorems

Let's define a probability space $(\Omega$, $\mathcal{F}$, $\mathbb{P})$ and consider a nonnegative random variable $Y$ defined on it such that $Y\in\mathcal{L}^{1}$.

Since, for a constant $c$, it **always** holds true that:
\begin{equation}
Y \mathbb{1}_{\{Y>c\}}\leq Y
\end{equation}
am I allowed to apply *Lebesgue's Dominated Convergence Theorem* to state that:
\begin{equation}
\lim\limits_{c\rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{E}\{Y \mathbb{1}_{\{Y>c\}}\}=\mathbb{E}\{\lim\limits_{c\rightarrow\infty} Y \mathbb{1}_{\{Y>c\}}\} = 0 
\end{equation}
$\big($where the last equation follows from the fact that $\lim\limits_{c\rightarrow\infty} Y \mathbb{1}_{\{Y>c\}}=0$ a.s., hence $\mathbb{E}\{\lim\limits_{c\rightarrow\infty} Y \mathbb{1}_{\{Y>c\}}\}=\mathbb{E}\{0\}=0\big)$?

---

I think I am allowed to do so, but I would like to have a confirmation about that

Comment: It works if $\mathbb{E}[Y]$ is finite.

Comment: Yes, I've forgotten this important detail, $Y\in\mathcal{L}^{1}$. I add it right now by editing @Mindlack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it works, but dominated convergence only works for sequences.

So actually, you should show for every sequence $(c_n)_n$ with $c_n \to + \infty$ that

$$\lim_n \mathbb{E}[Y1_{\{Y > c_n\}}] = 0$$

in order to conclude that

$$\lim_{c \to \infty} \mathbb{E}[Y1_{\{Y > c\}}]= 0$$